# Android Support4Demos build failure

Tags: android, import, demo, v4l

I tried to get the SupportDemos run, but when I import the demo I get several failures in the Project.

I don't understand why there are so many failures and how I could solve them, I am not advanced enough to get them out.
I will give you some samples:

First in class FragmentCustomAnimationSupport they used in line 75 the method

> ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_left_enter,
>                   R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit,
>                   R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,
>                   R.anim.fragment_slide_right_exit);

but this method just supports 2 arguments.

Second in class LoaderCustomSupport they used the import

> import android.widget.SearchView;

which can't be resolved.

As Api lvl I chose 8 and I added the supportv4 Library. There a some more failures can someone tell me how to solve this and get the supportv4Demos run?

I don't think Android will offer me non-working sample demos so the problem should be at my side.

Maybe I made a mistake in importing the samples? ..

My Steps: new Android project -> from existing source -> \extras\android\support\v4\samples\Support4Demos -> with api lvl 8 ->add support library

Someone know what I did wrong?

Comment: it's well knowed "bug" in this demos ... simply, there is no android.widget.SearchView in support library, and sine is "newer" API(11) it will not work on older devices

Comment: ahh ok .. this sucks xD .. nevertheless thanks

Comment: please see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055709/android-support4demos-crashes/16120836#16120836